# Gnome commander browse archive

Tags: filemanager

In Total Commander, on Windows, I can open supported archive (zip, tar, rar, etc.) as if it was an ordinary directory and browse the contents.

Is this possible in Gnome Commander (`gnome-commander`)?

Comment: in Gnome , it can automatically open all the files you mentioned with archive manger by default.

Comment: He is talking about the package `gnome-commander`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Gnome Commander

Assuming you are talking about `gnome-commander` - it seems like it is not browing the archives out of the box. In my case it is using the default handler for the related archive.

You can define custom handlers for defined extensions as follows.

- Please start the application
- Navigate to 'Settings' -> 'Options'
- Select the tab 'Programs'
- Create a custom rule in the 'Other favorite apps' section

But this doesn't mean it can directly browse the archive. It just allows you to define which program should be used for certain extensions.

## Alternatives

I would recommend using `mc` - aka Midnight commander as it offers what you are looking for and has most likely even a smaller fingerprint.

[image]

You can easily install it like that

```
sudo apt-get install mc
```

Comment: Wow, that looks like Norton Commander. That might just do the trick. Thanks.